# how to reset function into AJAX Response?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, contentflow

I have write the following code into AJAX to change the tab.

```
  $("a").click(function(event){
      if ($.browser.msie != true && $.browser.version != 8.0){
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass("current") == false){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/getvideofeed',
          success: function(data) {

            $('.flow').html(data);
            cf._init();


          },

          data: {'playlistid': $(this).attr("pid")}
        });
      $(".current").removeClass("current");
      console.log($(this).parent().addClass("current"));
      }}
    });
```

when i changed the TAB. the `cf._init();` function getting called more than one time... means when i clicked 1st tab it will be called twice. when i clicked to next tab again cf._init() function will be called thrice and so on.

so my problem is how to reset `cf._init()` function after ajax called has been finished ? or how to called `cf._init()` function only once each time when i clicked any of the tab .

Comment: Are you sure you're not attaching the same listener multiple times?

Comment: Is it the listener attached in the cf._init() function?

Comment: Your click handler might be getting executed multiple times. Check if a `console.log` statement added just above `$("a").click(function(event)` gets executed only once.

Comment: @srvikram13 yes clicked function is executed only once but cf._init() function executed more than once

Comment: Put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/bt997/) to learn how to simulate an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

The function cf._init() should be executed on Ajax success
if cf._init() called more than once, than probably the Ajax is being performed more than once.

For start I suggest putting async property as follows:
async: false

so Ajax call will wait until it is finished.
This way will enable you to debug how come Ajax call is made more than once.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure cf._init() is not calling ajax again ... 2nd why not call init when ajax is done or complete :

```
 var request = $.ajax({"url":url});
 request.done( function(data){ } );
```